# Find the general solution to the equation $y^{''}-6y^{'}+8y=5xe^{2x}+2e^{4x}\sin x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solving the homogeneous equation
$$y^{''}-6y^{'}+8=0\Rightarrow \lambda^2-6\lambda+8=0\Rightarrow \lambda_1=2,\lambda_2=4$$

General solution to this homogeneous equation is $y_h=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{4x}$.

How to find one particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation?

Answer (score 2):

With *superposition of solutions:*

Find a particular solution $y_0(x)$ for $ y''-6y'+8=x\mathrm e^{2x} $, a particular solution $ z_0(x) $ for  $y''-6y'+8=x\mathrm e^{4x}\sin x$. A particular solution for   $y''-6y'+8=5x\mathrm e^{2x}+2\mathrm e^{4x}\sin x$ will be $5y_0(x)+2z_0(x)$.

For a right-hand side of the form $p(x)\mathrm e^{2x}$, $p(x)$ a polynomial of degree $d$, as $\mathrm e^{2x}$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation, $y_0(x)$ will have the form  $xq(x)\mathrm e^{2x}$, with $\deg q=d$.

As for the right-hand side $\mathrm e^{4x}\sin x$, it is the imaginary part of $\mathrm e^{(4+\mathrm i)x}$, which leads to a particular solution of the form $K\mathrm e^{(4+\mathrm i)x}$. Then take the imaginary part of this particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

Particular solution we find with method of undermined coefficients
$$y_p={{e}^{4 x}}\, \left( A \sin{(x)}+B \cos{(x)}\right) +{{e}^{2 x}} x\, \left( C x+D\right) $$
We get
$${{e}^{4 x}}\, \left( -2 B \sin{(x)}-A \sin{(x)}-B \cos{(x)}+2 A \cos{(x)}\right) +{{e}^{2 x}}\, \left( -4 C x-2 D+2 C\right)\\ =2 {{e}^{4 x}} \sin{(x)}+5 {{e}^{2 x}} x,$$
$$-2 B-A=2,\quad 2 A-B=0,\quad -4 C=5,\quad 2 C-2 D=0,$$
$$A=-\frac{2}{5},\quad B=-\frac{4}{5},\quad C=-\frac{5}{4},\quad D=-\frac{5}{4},$$
$$y_p={{e}^{4 x}}\, \left( -\frac{2 \sin{(x)}}{5}-\frac{4 \cos{(x)}}{5}\right) +{{e}^{2 x}}\, \left( -\frac{5 x}{4}-\frac{5}{4}\right)  x\\=
-\frac{2 {{e}^{4 x}}\, \left( \sin{(x)}+2 \cos{(x)}\right) }{5}-\frac{5 {{e}^{2 x}} x\, \left( x+1\right) }{4},$$
General solution is
$$y=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{4x}+y_p$$

Comment: +1 for the detailed calculations. However, you should not "undermine" the "undetermined" coefficients.